# How do you calculate all the values in a column in SQLite (Android) into a new variable for textview?

Tags: sqlite, variables, textview

My database takes in a bill (name, date due, amount of bill) and adds them to a row. So now I populate 5 rows with dummy bills at varying amounts. What I'm trying to do is combine the total of all bills entered into a textview.

So if I row1 bill is $50.00 and row2 bill is $25.00, how can I add them both and connect the total ($75.00) to a textview that will update itself each time a new bill is added or an old bill is subtracted?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a simple `SELECT SUM(ammount) FROM table` on your table, and make that update every time a new row is added.

Comment: I see what you are saying Draiken and thx for the reply. I'm having problems since I'm new to SQLite (Android). in the end, I want the total to update the TextView on a seperate activity:

Comment: public long createRentEntry(String rName, String rDate, String rAmount) {
  //inserts to table
  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  cv.put(RENT_NAME, rName);
  cv.put(RENT_DATE, rDate);
  cv.put(RENT_AMOUNT, rAmount);
  
  return ourRDatabase.insert(RENT_DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);  
 }

Comment: <pre>public String getData() {
  String columns[] = new String[]{RENT_ID, RENT_NAME, RENT_DATE, RENT_AMOUNT};
  Cursor c = ourRDatabase.query(RENT_DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
  String result = "";<code>

Comment: int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(RENT_ID);
  int iName = c.getColumnIndex(RENT_NAME);
  int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(RENT_DATE);
  int iAmount = c.getColumnIndex(RENT_AMOUNT);
  
  for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
   result = result + c.getString(iRow) + "\t\t" + c.getString(iName) + "\t\t" +
   c.getString(iDate) + "\t\t\t$" + c.getString(iAmount) + "\n";
  }
  return result;
 }

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I figured it out! I made a seperate method called "getAmountTotal" in my helper and applied what you said. Then referenced it my main activity's textview. It didn't work at first, but then I forgot I need the database open. So I moved the code to set my text view between calling open and close and that made it work! Thanks again for your input!!! :)